# Usage of "at one point"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Someone wrote:

> At one point a funny story happened to me.

It continues:

> I'm studying English in the private English language school called SPEAK UP. Several days ago one teacher invited the students to a pub quiz, **right**. When I got there, they had already settled down in the pub....

I changed the first sentence  to:

> Some time ago/ once a funny story happened to me.

I think "At one point" is used to begin a story like :

> At one point we stopped at a gas station....

Before describing an event, but not a good choice for the sentence above. Right?

In general, what's its usage?

Beside I think the *right* in the continuation of the story doesn't sound good and is extra. Right?

Comment: Because it's a story, it's very hard to judge without reading the whole story. It's quite possible that a writer may deliberately choose to be vague and jump right into the middle of the story right from the start. -- Consider, a simplified narrative such as: *He was looking at her curiously. It was raining heavily outside. He tried to recall if he had ever met her because the face looked so familiar. After finishing her coffee, she left. He was now alone again. The barista smiled at him. He lifted his cup and sipped his coffee again.* -- We don't know who she was, where he was, etc.

Comment: @damkerngt. I added more info...

Comment: Ahmad, please stop asking multiple questions in one. Don't label the question as one about "at one point" and then also ask about "right" in an aside.

Answer (score 2):

The implication of *at one point* is "at one point in time", that is, at one point in a series of points in space-time.

> Driving along the narrow mountain roads was dangerous. At one point,
>   we thought the truck was going to topple into the gorge.

Thus, to begin a statement  with *at one point* would be a *non-sequitur*. There would have been no explicit setting of context to explain it, as in the mountain road example above, and so it could confuse the listener or reader. However, a long-standing convention of storytelling is that a storyteller has the freedom to begin a story *in medias res*.  There, the non-sequitur is a narrative device not a logical shortcoming.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation but could you please clarify that "at one point" can begin something like "at one point, a funny thing happened to me"? based on your explanation it is not an event in a series of events. But what are other alternatives to begin this story?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your question. "clarify that it can begin something".  Do you mean "clarify *whether*...?" A tried and true alternative would be to begin with "Once". It is understood to refer to some time in the past.

Comment: yes *whether*. I mean please directly tell me whether  "at one point" is natural in that sentence or not, it seems you mean not.

Comment: Please read my answer over again, as it answers the question whether to begin a sentence with "At one point" is "natural".   If, by *natural*, you are excluding storytelling, then it is not natural to begin a statement in that way. It would be a non-sequitur. It would be like beginning a conversation with "And then..."

Comment: You indirectly say the exact usage of it, but it doesn't mean English for whatever reason won't use it in the case above too. For example this link http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/at-one-point says it's used to begin  a story so I got doubtful how?

Comment: You need to read more carefully, Ahmad. That is *not* what that page says. It says just the opposite.  [“At one point” is used for something that happened in the middle of an event, not at the beginning or end.]

Comment: Right true. Sorry! But anyway starting your excellent answer with a simple "no" is very helpful to the readers like me.

Comment: But you did not ask a simple question -- it was complicated by the storytelling component, and so a simple answer would not have been good. @Damkerng T made that point early on in a comment.  Also, I was explaining *why* it might not be a good choice.

Comment: Anyway I am thankful for your answers but my first question was *I think it is used before describing an event, but not a good choice for the sentence above. Right?* The answer could be "Right! it's not", and then saying why. Your answers mostly covers the second part of my question "*In general, what's its usage?*" :), anyway thank you!

Comment: But it *is* used before describing an event, but only if the event is part of a larger encompassing series of events.

Comment: are these events often similar? For example *I usually go cinema on Fridays. At one point, I decided to go there by bus...*

Comment: **Usually** doesn't establish an encompassing *series* of events but a general state of affairs. For that reason,"at one point" would be marginal there, though I suspect that very few speakers would bother to split hairs. But consider the difference between **usually** and the following sentence: *For the past year, I've been taking a cab on Saturday nights to the cinema downtown, although at one point, when the cab drivers were on strike, I had to take the bus.*

Answer (score 1):

**At one point** is used to describe the situation at one particular, unspecified, time. It is usually used close to the end of a scene in a story to provide additional information about what happened during that scene.

For example, imagine describing an afternoon outing, part of which involved a rowing boat and either incompetent oarsmen or drunk passengers. After telling the story of this scene you might add:

> At one point, there were more people in the water than in the boat.

You are not saying when exactly in the scene this happened: it is completely unrelated to the sequence of events. You are simply providing additional information to help the listener or reader visualise what happened.

Note that it is not correct to start a story with

> ... a funny **story** happened to me.

The story is a **description of what happened**, not **what actually happened**. When telling this kind of story, the conventional word for the event itself is **thing**

> ... a funny **thing** happened to me.

If you want to start a story with **a funny thing happened to me**, you should really to give a general impression of when, and maybe where, it happened:

> A funny thing happened to me at work yesterday...
>   A funny thing happened to me last week...

There is actually a musical and a film entitled [A funny thing happened on the way to the forum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Funny_Thing_Happened_on_the_Way_to_the_Forum).

Regarding **right** in your story: this is something that people sometimes say, but rarely write.  It would work if this paragraph is dialogue- something that a character in your story says- but it would not look natural if it were a part of your own story.

Comment: Thank you for the "thing" point, but yet we don't say "at one point, a funny thing happened to me" do we? if not, what are the other alternatives to start this story?

Comment: No, you cannot start a story with "at one point": this expression can only be used near the end of a scene in the story. I have updated my answer to explain how to use "a funny thing happened..." to start a story.